# How to read and name different CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv

I would like to work on several csv files to make some comparisons, so I wrote this code to read the different csv files I have:

```
path <- "C:\\data\\"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

My csv files are something like this:

```
Start Time,End Time,Total,Diffuse,Direct,Reflected
04/09/14 00:01:00,04/09/14 00:01:00,2.221220E-003,5.797364E-004,0.000000E+000,1.641484E-003,
04/09/14 00:02:00,04/09/14 00:02:00,2.221220E-003,5.797364E-004,0.000000E+000,1.641484E-003,
04/09/14 00:03:00,04/09/14 00:03:00,2.221220E-003,5.797364E-004,0.000000E+000,1.641484E-003,
(...)
```

Using my code, R separate correctly all files, but for each of them it creates a table adding a more extra space at the beginning:

```
                 |Start Time       |End Time     |Total        |Diffuse      |Direct       |Reflected
04/09/14 00:01:00|04/09/14 00:01:00|2.221220E-003|5.797364E-004|0.000000E+000|1.641484E-003|NA
...
```

How can I fix it?

Moreover, considering that the original name of each file is really long, is it possible to name each data.frame using the last letters of the file? Or just a cardinal number?

Comment: R is working correctly: your CSV file contains more columns than there are column headers, due to the trailing comma.

Comment: You might want to consider reading the files into a list, instead of `assign`ing them to the global environment. For example: `results <- vector("list", length = length(files)); for(i in seq_along(files)){ file <- files[[i]]; results[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0(path, file))}` If you want to keep the filename, just do `results[[file]] <- read.csv(...)`. If they have the same format, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows` to unite them.

Comment: He's saying the titles are shifted over by 1. An easy fix could be to just run `names(df) <- c(names(df)[-1],"DROP")` and then just `df <- df[,-"DROP"]`

Comment: @AmitKohli That won’t work, you first have to convert the rownames into a column. Using tibble/dplyr that would be `df %>% rownames_to_column() %>% setNames(c(colnames(.)[-1], 'DROP')) %>% select(-DROP)`. However, it seems cleaner to fix the faulty CSV files.

Comment: I like your dplyr approach, but nothing in my solution involves rownames? Agree it's cleaner to fix teh faulty csv files. Just said this way was perhaps easier ;)

Comment: @AmitKohli The rownames are in OP’s example, and looking at the CSV file, these should actually not be rownames but rather be the first column, with colname “Start Time”.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fixing the csv file trying to eliminate the last comma

Comment: @KonradRudolph those are column names bro

Comment: @AmitKohli No, I’m talking about the *row names*, i.e. the value `04/09/14 00:01:00` in OP’s example.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean. No, they are not rownames, that's exactly the problem he's having. Look carefully @ the example file provided under `My csv files are something like this`. You'll see there's 6 column headers and 6 columns. The problem is exactly getting R to read that correctly

Comment: oh... duh. Posting a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the data.table package - it's faster and for non-blank columns in the end, it converts those to `NA` (in my experience). Here's some code I wrote for a simialr task:

```
read_func <- function(z) {
  dat <- fread(z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(dat) <- c("start_time", "end_time", "Total", "Diffuse", "Direct", "Reflect")
  dat$start_tme <- as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$start_tme,
                    format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"), tz = "Pacific/Easter")
  patrn <- "([0-9][0-9][0-9])\\.csv"
  dat$type <- paste("Dataset",gsub(".csv", "", regmatches(z,regexpr(patrn, z))),sep="")
  return(as.data.table(dat))
}

path <- ".//Data/" 
file_list <- dir(path, pattern = "csv")
file_names <- unname(sapply(file_list, function(x) paste(path, x, sep = "")))
data_list <- lapply(file_names, read_func)

dat <- rbindlist(data_list, use.names = TRUE) 

rm(path, file_list, file_names)
```

This will give you a list with each item as the data.table from the corresponding file name. I assumed that all file names have a three digit number before the extension which I used to assign a variable `type` to each data.table. You can change `patrn` to match your specific use case. This way, when you combine all of them into a single data.table `dat`, you can always sort/filter based on type. For example, if youwanted to  plot `diffuse` vs `direct` for `Dataset158` and `datase222`, you could do the following:

```
ggplot(data = dat[type == 'Dataset158' | type == 'Dataset222'], 
       aes(x = Diffuse, y = Direct)) + geom_point()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're having a problem because your csv files have a blank column at the end... which makes your data end in a comma:

`04/09/14 00:01:00,04/09/14 00:01:00,2.221220E-003,5.797364E-004,0.000000E+000,1.641484E-003,`

This leads R to think your data consists of 7 columns rather than 6. The correct solution is to resave all your csv files correctly. Otherwise, R will see 7 columns but only 6 columnnames, and will logically think that the first column is rownames. Here you can apply the patch we came up with @konradrudolph:

`library(tibble)
df %>% rownames_to_column() %>% setNames(c(colnames(.)[-1], 'DROP')) %>% select(-DROP)`

where `df` is the data from the csv. But patches like this can lead to unexpected results... better save the csv files correctly.