# Read multiple text files into dataframes using r

Tags: r

I'm trying to read multiple text files into their individual dataframes using R

I tried
`files <- (Sys.glob("*.txt"))
listOfFiles <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header = FALSE,sep='|'))`

but this would create a list of them.

Is there a function to read them into multiple dataframe ?

Comment: `list2env()` Might need to set the names first. It would be "better" to keep them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbindlist` to then combine the list into a single `data.frame`:

```
dat <- rbindlist(listOfFiles, use.names = TRUE)
```

I'm assuming the different files have the same structure and col. names.

I would suggest using `data.table` and `fread` which are much faster. Infact, you can follow the approach from my answer here which ought to work in your case. [How to read and name different CSV files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284146/how-to-read-and-name-different-csv-files-in-r/46612637#46612637)